# On the sign of characteristic curves in partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This was something I noticed as I was trying to practice solving PDEs using the method of characteristics.

The text has the following example: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$$

This should be easy enough. I let $p(x,y) = x$ and solve for $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$. When I do that I get: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =0 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =- x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = -x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = -x$$

This should be easy enough from there, I would have $\int \partial y= - x \partial x \Rightarrow y=-\frac{1}{2}x^2+ C$ and $y+\frac{1}{2}x^2 = C$ so $u(x,y) = y+\frac{1}{2}x^2$. General solution is $f(y+\frac{1}{2}x^2)$ where f is an arbitrary function.

SO what's the problem? The text says that  $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=x$ not $-x$. Anyone know what's up? I have consistently found that the my HW solutions and text say this should be a different sign than what i get when I just solve for $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$. What am I missing? I figure its probably something simple enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest  to (a) stop writing things like $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}$; (b) more generally, before writing anything like $\partial  A /\partial  B $, always pause to think: in what sense is $A$ a function of $B$?

A more specific advice: remember the vector calculus theorem that if  $y$ is a function of $x$ given by   equation   $F(x,y)=C$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\partial F/\partial x}{\partial F/\partial y}$. Here is this minus sign again.

As for the original problem, it does not hurt to check your reasoning geometrically. The equation says that the directional derivative of $u$ along the vector $(1,x)$ is zero. We want to find integral curves of the vector field $(1,x)$, because $u$ will be constant along them. The slope of such curves at $(x,y)$ is $x/1=x$. Hence, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x$  is the ODE we want to solve.

Comment: Thanks that helps. I was just sort of taking things at their word that the sign was what it was, this helps me to understand better.